# how to solve Kernel configuration is invalid issues

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to build module.

But here's some issues.

> ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
>            include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
>            Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
>
> WARNING: Symbol version dump ./Module.symvers
>              is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.`

And here's my makefile

```
ifeq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)


KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

modules:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

modules_install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions

.PHONY: modules modules_install clean

else
    # called from kernel build system: just declare what our modules are
    obj-m := hello.o hellop.o seq.o jit.o jiq.o sleepy.o complete.o \
             silly.o faulty.o kdatasize.o kdataalign.o
endif
```

I tried building like this:

```
export KERNELDIR=/path/to/extern/linux/source
make
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is unclear in phrase "include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing. Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it."? The error itself means that kernel source directory, which you point to, isn't ready for build neither kernel itself nor modules for it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Woo-Hyun, could you solve the problem?

Comment: @Tsyvarev well in my case, I get the same error if my custom kernel module is included and get no error if I exclude my kernel module. That means that kernel source directory is ready to build kernel and is valid.

Answer (score 17):

### Step 1

re-install the `linux-headers`.

---

### prerequisites

- terminal access(`bash presumably`)
- root privileges

  - (or a user who can do 'sudo')

First, we try to re install (using APT) the `linux-headers` package -**but** adding your *specific kernel version*.  Which is determined by  the following command: `$(uname -r)`

and to do it all in one line:

---

`sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Then, as we talk about the kernel, and making changes to it (quite major too, a reinstall of a kernel that is) we want to reboot as soon as the APT command is done:

---

`sudo reboot`

If you get it couldn't find any package, (or similar) (from apt)
try `apt update` and re-try the above.

---

### Logs

Do check  `/var/log/kern.log`  for any messages that is,

- `cat /var/log/kern.log`

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem with the following commands:

1. From your built sources take the most recent `.config` file with kernel configuration. Copy it to `kernel-source` directory (e.g.: `build/tmp/work-shared/lmm-corei7/kernel-source`).
2. Run `make prepare`.

Comment: didn't quite understand from where to copy the file, sorry if it's because of my poor english knowledge or poor linux knowledge haha

Comment: @DanielSaito No worries at all, I am a bit unsure myself,  where would we try to copy it from and to?  copy there .config file  is a bit  broad :)

Comment: From your built sources take the most recent .config with kernel parameters. Copy it to kernel-source directory (e.g.: build/tmp/work-shared/lmm-corei7/kernel-source).

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours on the same problem, having the same error message : ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid...

The solution was so simple...
I was running `sudo make` and this created the errors.
After having done what is suggested by William Martens (reinstall the headers and reboot), I logged as root, and the module built perfectly.
To be sure, I did a second test with an admin account and `sudo make`, and it failed again. So I am sure this is the reason. I noticed also that after a fail, I have to reinstall the headers otherwise, even in root, it fails.

This happened on a Debian 11 with kernel 5.10.0-16-amd64.