# Spack - ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid

Tags: linux, openmpi, spack

I'm trying to install packages with Spack following the [instruction on how to install OpenMPI](https://developer.amd.com/spack/hpc-applications-openmpi/).

When I install packages like xpmem, I get a first error saying `ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid`. Later in the output I get compilation errors like `error: passing argument 4 of ‘proc_create_data’ from incompatible pointer type`.

I already tried to re-install linux-headers as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361990/how-to-solve-kernel-configuration-is-invalid-issues). Also I tried to use different versions of the GCC compiler as well as xpmem package and used a clean PATH variable as recommended by Spack. But nothing seems to fix it. Also on another machine it yielded the same error (Both are Ubuntu 20.04.3).

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As a package manager, spack should install xpmem's dependencies, then try and compile xpmem itself.  When encountering build errors, the next step is to try [spack cd](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/packaging_guide.html#spack-cd) and running the compile steps manually.