# Trying to do sudo make for linux driver

Tags: linux, makefile, module, driver, raspberry-pi4

I have problem with building Makefile for linux module, which I want to put on Raspberry Pi4.But when i try to do **sudo make** it  doesn't work and terminal show me this error.

```
make -C /lib/modules/6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8'
  SYNC    include/config/auto.conf.cmd
  GEN     Makefile
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.20+rpt-common-rpi/scripts/Makefile.build:41: /usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.20+rpt-common-rpi/scripts/basic/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.20+rpt-common-rpi/scripts/basic/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.20+rpt-common-rpi/Makefile:644: scripts_basic] Error 2
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.20+rpt-common-rpi/Makefile:786: include/config/auto.conf.cmd: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.20+rpt-common-rpi/Makefile:809: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.20+rpt-common-rpi/Makefile:246: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

I have tried to find solutions on other forums, but unlucky.

Comment: (1) Don't run `make` as a privileged user, except to install already-built software to privileged locations.  (2) Your build is looking for files that are not present.  We can't tell you for sure why not, but the diagnostics suggest to me that you may have skipped some kind of preliminary configuration step.

Comment: When i type make it shows up this:  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

Comment: And if I type make oldconfig && make prepare: make: *** No rule to make target 'oldconfig'.  Stop.

Comment: Hi,  I have found solution on this post, it finally worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361990/how-to-solve-kernel-configuration-is-invalid-issues